# Find the region where an integral is defined

Tags: complex-analysis

How to determine where $$f(z)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{tz}}{1+t^2} \, dt$$ is defined and holomorphic using [Morera's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) and [Fubini's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) theorem?

Comment: So, what would you need to do to apply Morera's theorem to show that $f(z)$ is analytic in a region $G$?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: what happens if limits of integration is from -1 to 1?

Comment: @abby:The integral has no problem at these points. See the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179088/showing-a-function-defined-from-an-integral-is-entire), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363087/moreras-theorem-of-entire-function). The region of convergence of the integral is $ Re(z) \leq 0 \,.$ To prove $f(z)$ is analytic, we appeal to Morera's theorem which states that a continuous, complex-valued function ƒ defined on a connected open set $D$ (in your case $D=\{z: Re(z)< 0 \})$ in the complex plane that satisfies
$$ \oint_{\gamma} f(z)\, dz = 0 $$
for every closed piecewise $C_1$ curve $γ$ in $D$ must be holomorphic on $D$.

Applying the theorem to your case, we have

$$ \oint_{\gamma} f(z) dz = \oint \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{{\rm e}^{zt}}{t^2+1}dt dz = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2+1}\oint_{\gamma} {\rm e}^{zt} dz \,dt = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t^2+1} (0) dt = 0 \,.$$

The inner integral equals 0, since ${\rm e}^{zt}$ is analytic and hence by Cauchy theorem the integral is zero. The interchanging of the integrals is justified by the uniform convergence of the $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{tz}}{1+t^2} \, dt $ or you can just apply [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).