# How to prove error function $\mbox{erf}$ is entire (i.e., analytic everywhere)?

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, contour-integration, error-function

How do I prove the error function $$ \mbox{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{z} e^{-t^{2}} dt. $$ is entire?

Could you give me some scratch proof?

Comment: What does 'entire' mean? Do you mean normalized?

Comment: You can ude [Morera's theorm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201444/find-the-region-where-an-integral-is-defined/201627#201627).

Comment: I'm sure I saw a question about the error function being entire just recently, but I can't find it. Was that yours? Did you delete it?

Comment: @PhilH What I mean by 'entire' is 'analytic everywhere (the whole complex plane)'.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thanks! I will try using it.

Comment: @joriki Yep... Since I edited that post too many times, I deleted it and reposted it dropping 'the boundness' part from the previous one. Does it violate any rule here?

Comment: @julypraise: See the answer.

Comment: @julypraise: I don't think there's a formalized rule against it. If you edited the post so much that it had essentially become a different question, posting a new question might make sense. However, thoughts, comments, votes, ... get lost if you do this; that should be taken into account. A question should definitely not be deleted for the purpose of evading the bad impression generated by critical comments and/or downvotes. (I'm not saying that's what you did, but it happens a lot.)

Comment: @joriki Ohu.. I didn't know that because I'm kind of new to this. I will definitely keep that in mind from this time on. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179088/showing-a-function-defined-from-an-integral-is-entire). First make the change of variables $ t=zy $, then advance with the proof as in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201444/find-the-region-where-an-integral-is-defined/201627#201627). Changing the variables results in the following integral

$$ \text{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{[0,z]} e^{-t^2}\,dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,{\int _{0}^{1}\!{z\,{\rm e}^{-{z}^{2}{y}^{2}}}{dy}}
 \,.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $[0,z]$ denote the straight-line path from $0$ to $z$. Then we define $$\text{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{[0,z]} e^{-t^2}\,dt.$$

Now note, using [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) (and the analyticity of $e^{-t^2}$), that
$$\frac{\text{erf}(z+h) - \text{erf}(z)}{h} = \frac{2}{\pi h}\int_{[0,z+h] - [0,z]} e^{-t^2}\,dt = \frac{2}{\pi h}\int_{[z,z+h]} e^{-t^2}\,dt.$$ Finally, this last expression tends to $(2/\pi)e^{-z^2}$ as $h\to 0$, so that $\text{erf}$ is differentiable with derivative $\text{erf}^\prime(z) = 2e^{-z^2}/\pi$. Indeed, let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $h$ small enough that $e^{-t^2}$ differs from $e^{-z^2}$ by less than $\epsilon$ as long as $|t-z|\leq|h|$. Then $$\left|\frac{1}{h}\int_{[z,z+h]} e^{-t^2}\,dt - e^{-z^2}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{h}\int_{[z,z+h]} (e^{-t^2} - e^{-z^2})\,dt\right| \leq \frac{1}{h} \int_{[z,z+h]} |e^{-t^2} - e^{-z^2}|\,dt \leq \epsilon.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've almost got your answer. But I didn't exactly get your Mean Value Theorem; may I ask you eactly which Mean Value Theorem you used?

Comment: Because it is a line integral, I'm quite confused about using Mean Value Theorem...

Comment: You can make a change of variables to make the domain of integration $[0,1]$, if you like. Alternatively, see the direct argument that I just added to the answer.

Comment: Okay I clearly got your last part. Thanks! But just to make sure my knowledge is right: there is no MVT that can be used line integral right? And that's why we need to make the domain of integration to [0,1] right, if we want to use MVT, rifht?

Comment: I'll leave you to formulate and to prove a version of MVT for line integrals, possibly by relating a line integral to an integral over $[0,1]$.

Comment: Sean: I wonder what it is you call Mean Value Theorem for *complex valued* functions. Could you make this point clearer?

Comment: I've removed all cryptic MVT references, to avoid any more confusion.