# Asymptotic behavior of entire functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, asymptotics

Which entire function $f\left(x\right)$ goes asymptotically to $\dfrac{e^{-x}}{x}$ as $x$ goes to infinity with $x$ positive? That is, $\left(e^{-x}/x \right)/f \left(x \right) \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Hint: What's wrong with $e^{-x}/x$ by itself?  Can you think of a way to subtract out that problem without affecting the behaviour at infinity?

Comment: I think that $e^ \left(-x \right)/x$ is not entire

Comment: Can you be more specific about why it isn't entire?  What $x$ is it not differentiable at?

Comment: Is it differentiable at $x = 0$?

Comment: What is $x$?  Is it complex?  Real?  When you say "as $x$ goes to infinity" do you mean "as $|x|$ goes to infinity" or are you asking about a particular direction (e.g. as $x \to \infty$ with x < 0)?

Comment: I would like to know what happens when $x$ is complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many entire functions which are asymptotic to $e^{-x}/x$ as $x \to \infty$ with $x > 0$.

Pick any finite $a > 0$ and any $\varphi \,\colon [0,a] \to \mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ such that

- $\varphi(0)$ is finite and nonzero,
- $\varphi$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $0$, and
- $\int_0^a|\varphi(t)|\,dt < \infty$.

Then the function

$$
f(z) = e^{-z} \int_0^a \varphi(t) e^{-zt}\,dt
$$

is entire by [Morera's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/179097/5531) and

$$
f(z) \sim e^{-z}/z
$$

as $z \to \infty$ with $|\arg z| \leq \pi/2 - \delta$ for any fixed $\delta > 0$ by [Watson's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson's_lemma).

I haven't the faintest idea for how to compile a list of all functions with the desired asymptotic character, though.

Comment: Dear Antonio, thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

The reason $\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$ is not entire is that it has a pole at $0$. Note, however, that away from $0$, the function $x$ has no zeros, so you can divide $e^{-x}$ by $x$ and get a holomorphic function. Close to $0$, you can express $e^{-x} = 1 + xf(x)$ where $f(x) = \frac{ e^{-x} - 1}{x}$ is entire (just write out the series expansion of $e^{-x}$). You thus find $e^{-x} = \frac{1}{x} + f(x)$, where $\frac{1}{x}$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity, and $f(x)$ is your sought entire function.

Comment: As $x \to \infty$ with $x > 0$ your function $f(x)$ is asymptotic to $-1/x$, not $e^{-x}/x$.

Comment: Fair point. I assumed the author of the question wanted $e^{-x}/x - f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, and that's what this function does. Also, it is unique with this property. I guess it also makes sense to ask for $(e^{-x}/x)/f(x) \to 1$.

Comment: Ah, I see how you were interpreting it now.  That makes sense too.