# Morera's theorem of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

> For each fixed $n$, show that $$f_n(z)=\int_1^nt^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$$ is an
>   entire function of $z$.

From Morera 's theorem:

> If a continuous, complex-valued function $f$ in a domain $D$ that
>   satisfies
>
> $$\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0 $$
>
> for every closed contour in $D$, then $f$ is analytic.

From this theorem how can I show that my function is indeed continuous? Do I prove this straight from the definition of continuity?

A hint which was provided, which I don't understand why, goes:$$\text{Look at:} \ |f(z_1)-f(z_2)|\le \int_1^n\frac{e^{-t}}{t}|t^{z_1}-t^{z_2}|dt \ \text{where},\\ z_1=x_1+iy_1 \\ z_2=x_2+iy_2$$

thus I must bound this but I don't know how to go from here? Any hints please?

Comment: You don't need Morera if you only care about continuity. THe hint suggests that you bound $|t^{z_1}-t^{z_2}|$ by $M|z_1-z_2|$ uniformly on $[1,n]$. This will show after integration that $f$ is Lipschitz, hence continuous.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179088/showing-a-function-defined-from-an-integral-is-entire) is how you can use Morera's theorem.

Comment: @julien I am having trouble continuing so that it is bounded to $M|z_1-z_2|$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes I have looked at that before posting this question but I still don't understand how to go further along with the hint given using that.

Comment: @julien I am mistaken, I meant to say entire not just continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related problems: [I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201444/find-the-region-where-an-integral-is-defined). Just see this,

$$ \oint_\gamma f_n(z) dz = \oint_\gamma \int_1^nt^{z-1}e^{-t}dt dz = \int_1^n e^{-t}\frac{dt}{t}\oint_\gamma e^{z\ln t}  dz \,dt = \dots.  $$

Can you finish it. What kind of function is $e^{z\ln(t)}$?

**Added:** To prove continuity, advance like that

$$ |f_n(z+h)-f_n(z)| =  \Big|\int_1^n (e^{(z+h)\ln t}-e^{ z \ln t }) \frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt \Big| $$

$$ \leq \int_1^n \big|e^{(z+h)\ln t}-e^{ z \ln t }\big| \frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt \leq M e^{-1} |h|\int_{1}^{n} \ln t\frac{1}{t}dt\dots. $$

Can you finish the task? Notice that, I used the mean value theorem to find the last inequality and $ e^{-t} \leq e^{-1} $ for $t\in [1,n]$.

Comment: Why would $e^{z\ln(t)}$ complete this proof?

Comment: @user71642: Just note that, $e^{z\ln(t)}$ is an analytic function in $z$, so the inner integral is zero by Cauchy theorem, That implies $\oint_\gamma f_n(z) dz =0$.

Comment: Thank you! And how will I show that it is continuous? If it is continuous and analytic then it is entire which completes the proof?

Comment: @user71642: You are very welcome.