# Is the integral $\int_1^{\infty} {A(t)}{t^{-s-1}}dt$ a holomorphic function of $s$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

My question is whether, for $Re(s)=\sigma > 3/4$, $$s\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{A(t)}{t^{s+1}}dt$$ is holomorphic, where $A(x)=O(x^{3/4})$.

Under absolute value, it is easy to see that the integral converges to some real number. But I am not sure if without it.

Comment: Try to use Morena's theorem. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363087/moreras-theorem-of-entire-function).

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201444/find-the-region-where-an-integral-is-defined).

Comment: According to that page, my $f(z)$ is $\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{A(t)}{t^{z+1}}dt$?