# Find the domain for which the function $f(z)=\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{tz}}{1+t^2}dt$ is defined and holomorphic?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

We need to find out the domain for which the following function is defined and holomorphic:

$$f(z)=\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{tz}}{1+t^2}dt$$

How do we proceed to this kind of problem?

Any hints please?

Comment: The first thing to do is to make some kind of guess at which values of $z$ will work. Which ones do you think the integral will converge for?

Comment: There was a mistake in the question. Sorry.

Comment: Hint: $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{z^n}{n!}\qquad a_n=\int_{-1}^1\ldots dt,$$ hence, for every $n$, $$|a_n|\leqslant\ldots$$ which proves that the radius of convergence is $_____$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179088/showing-a-function-defined-from-an-integral-is-entire

Answer (score 2):

Morera's theorem is probably the simplest approach (for questions such as these -- Did's hint gives a quicker solution in this particular case). First show that $f$ is continuous. (I'll leave that to you.) Then, if $\gamma$ is any closed curve in $\mathbb{C}$,
\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz &= \int_{\gamma} \left( \int_0^1 \frac{e^{tz}}{1+t^2}\,dt \right) \,dz \\
&=  \int_{-1}^1 \left( \int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{tz}}{1+t^2}\,dz \right) \,dt \\
&=  \int_{-1}^1 \left( \int_{\gamma} e^{tz} \,dz \right) \frac{1}{1+t^2} \,dt = 
\int_{-1}^1 0\,dt = 0\\
\end{align}
where the inner integral (after changing the order of integration) vanishes due to Cauchy's integral theorem. Morera's theorem then shows that $f$ is holomorphic everywhere.